# Does width of line in canvas depend on it's size

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I met the following problem. After drawing line on several canvas of the same thickness, thickness of displayed lines was identical (see print-screen)

Sizes of canvases are not the same. I'm wondering does thickness of displayed line depends on sizes of canvas? And whether it's possible to draw on canvas without determining it's width.

here's the screen

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas size attributes (width and height) determine the number of logical pixels in canvas. The CSS size of canvas must equal canvas size to get exactly 1 to 1 mapping of pixels

Comment: so you saying that I should do `$canvas.css({width: W})` after `$canvas.width(W)`

Comment: Yes, that way the pixels match. Also draw lines to middle of pixels to get crisp lines. i.e use x + 0.5 instead of integer x

Comment: doing `$canvas.css({width: W})` after `$canvas.width(W)` seem to have no effect :(

Comment: Probably best to just leave the CSS width/height undefined since you just want them to equal the attribute width/height anyway. The other thing that can affect your line widths, at least slightly is the sub pixel rendering. Can you post the code you're using to draw your lines?